# Should I use inheritance or composition for ReceivedLineItem class in this scenario?

Tags: c#, oop

I have two classes - LineItem and ReceivedLineItem. A line item can be received multiple times. For example, user orders 5 laptops (a laptop being a line item) and each week the user receives 1 laptop. In this case should I go with a ReceivedLineItem IS a LineItem or a LineItem HAS multiple received line items?

```
public class LineItem
{
    public int LineItemID { get; set; }
    public int QuantityOrdered { get; set; }

    //public List<ReceivedLineItem> ReceivedLineItems { get; set; }

}

public class ReceivedLineItem: //LineItem
{
    public int ReceivedLineItemID { get; set; }
    public int QuantityReceived { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReceivedLineItem IS A LineItem might be a good choice.  Then you just need the QuantityReceived property.  LineItem HAS A ReceivedLineItem may not be a good design choice as there is a span of time between ordering and receiving.  So, no need to think about receiving information until later.  An order can be placed and then cancelled without being shipped/received, etc.

```
public class LineItem
    {
        public int LineItemID { get; set; }
        public int QuantityOrdered { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReceivedLineItem : LineItem
    {
        public int QuantityReceived { get; set; }
    }

    // execution code somewhere..
        ...
        public List<ReceivedLineItem> Items { get; set; }
```